# React js: Fetching data from an api(ipstack)

Tags: json, reactjs, api, fetch-api

I am fetching data from an API about the location and  I got the data in the local server. when I uploaded my project in firebase hosting and also netlify, I was getting an error like Could not fetch the data.

```
const [b, setb] = useState(false) 
useEffect(() => {
    const getdata = async () => {
      const response = await fetch(req)
      const d = await response.json()
      setdata(d)
      console.log(d)
    }
    getdata()
  }, [req])

{b ? (
        <div>
          <h3>Continent: {data.continent_name}</h3>
          <h3>IP Address: {data.ip}</h3>
          <h3>Region: {data.region_name}</h3>
          <img
            src={data.location.country_flag}
            alt={data.region_name}
            height='250'
            width='400'
          />
          <h4>City: {data.city}</h4>
          <h4>Zipcode: {data.zip}</h4>
          <h4>Latitude:{data.latitude}</h4>
          <h4>Longitude: {data.longitude}</h4>
        </div>
      ) : (
        ''
      )}
      <button id='show' onClick={() => showdata()}>
        Get the info
      </button>
```

there is a show data function which changes the state of the b when the button is clicked. i didnot check any error or status of the request while i was fetching the data.

in console log i got this
Location.js:20 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://geo-location-75a53.web.app/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource 'http://api.ipstack.com/check?access_key=dfa398a47a39d967930dbdda13230919'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
(anonymous) @ Location.js:20
asyncToGenerator.js:6 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch```

Comment: IPStack offers SSL encryption with their paid plans. You can avoid the mixed content message by calling the `https` endpoint instead of `http`.